# Permission denied still gets added to .on() listener

Tags: firebase

I'm using firebase's `.on()` event listener to listen for entries inserted into my database in real time. I've noticed that even when a data insertion is denied, a user subscribed to the ref the data was supposed to be inserted into still gets that piece of data, even though in the database the data is never inserted.

I noticed this while developing the chat module of my web app. Here is a gif of the bug: https://gfycat.com/VariableFrailBasenji

I've set a validation rule on new messages that their length has to be under 200:

```
"$msg": { ".validate": "newData.val().length < 200"}
```

So when you see me paste in a bunch of letters, the console says the write gets denied, but the user who had the `.on()` subscription to that part of the database still got the message, even though it didn't get added to the database.

Anyways, this isn't really a post with a question, just wanted to share this strange bug that could potentially lead to data leakage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase SDK uses advanced techniques like latency compensation when you write to the database. This means that before the server has acknowledged a write it goes into an in-memory database cache and optimistically assumes the write will be allowed.

When the server denies the write, it will remove the incorrectly cached data and you should see a corresponding `child_removed` event.