# Prevent observer returning local "invalid" version of data after saving before save is eventually denied with `write` rule

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an observer on a path and when I write "invalid" that data to that path (i.e. data that will fail due to a `.write` rule) the observer is firing first with the data (locally cached perhaps?), and then again with the initial version of the data once the write has failed.

How can I prevent this observer from returning this "invalid"/local version? I would expect observers to only be given values that have been saved to the database i.e. passed all rules.

Disabling `FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled` doesn't affect this behavior.

Comment: I've seen this issue, in various forms, raised in a number of SO questions.  AFAIK there is no way to prevent this behavior. It's a consequence of the Firebase client/server architecture with data cached in the client and validation done on the server.  See this answer from a Firebase team member: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714445/4815718

Comment: @BobSnyder Thanks for the link to the other question  Very useful and great to hear it answered from a Firebase team member. I can understand the rationale behind that design decision but it's certainly not desirable in these use cases. Cheers!